# Why FORCING INDEX making this Query much slower on smaller datasets?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I am using MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu Server. The SQL involves 2 tables, `collection_notes` and `notes`. `collection_notes` is a relationship table to connect many-to-many relation between `collections` and `notes`

The structures're like:

```
collection_notes
---------
Field         Type      Null  Key Default Extra
id            int(11)   NO    PRI NULL    auto_increment
collection_id int(11)   YES   MUL NULL  
note_id       int(11)   YES   MUL NULL  
created_at    datetime  NO        NULL  
updated_at    datetime  NO        NULL  
user_id       int(11)   YES   MUL NULL  

notes
---------
Field                 Type          Null  Key
id                    int(11)       NO    PRI
created_at            datetime      NO              
updated_at            datetime      NO              
notebook_id           int(11)       YES   MUL 
shared                tinyint(1)    NO    MUL
slug                  varchar(100)  NO    UNI 
shared_at             datetime      YES   MUL 
seq_in_nb             int(11)       YES       
note_type             varchar(255)  YES      
locked                tinyint(1)    NO       
locked_at             datetime      YES       
likes_count           int(11)       YES      
image_file_name       varchar(255)  YES       
generating_image      int(11)       YES      
image_generated_at    int(11)       NO       
commentable           tinyint(1)    YES      
last_stopped_share_at datetime      YES       
bookmarks_count       int(11)       YES      
last_compiled_at      int(11)       NO       
first_shared_at       datetime      YES   MUL 
title_image           varchar(190)  YES       
deleted_at            datetime      YES   MUL 
comment_updated_at    int(11)       YES   MUL
```

`notes` has more columns.

Indexes from `collection_notes`:

```
Table             Non_unique  Key_name                                            Seq_in_index  Column_name    Collation   Cardinality Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type
collection_notes  0           PRIMARY                                             1             id             A           3874847     NULL      NULL           BTREE   
collection_notes  0           index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id 1             collection_id  A           138387      NULL      NULL    YES    BTREE   
collection_notes  0           index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id 2             note_id        A           3874847     NULL      NULL    YES    BTREE   
collection_notes  1           index_collection_notes_on_collection_id             1             collection_id  A           184516      NULL      NULL    YES    BTREE   
collection_notes  1           index_collection_notes_on_note_id                   1             note_id        A           3874847     NULL      NULL    YES    BTREE   
collection_notes  1           index_collection_notes_on_user_id                   1             user_id        A           82443       NULL      NULL    YES    BTREE
```

Indexes from `notes`:

```
Table Non_unique  Key_name                                  Seq_in_index  Column_name         Collation Cardinality Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type
notes 0           PRIMARY                                   1             id                  A         5434512     NULL      NULL          BTREE   
notes 0           index_notes_on_slug                       1             slug                A         5434512     NULL      NULL          BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_notebook_id                1             notebook_id         A         5434512     NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_shared_at                  1             shared_at           A         5434512     NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_shared_and_locked          1             shared              A         2           NULL      NULL          BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_shared_and_locked          2             locked              A         6           NULL      NULL          BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_first_shared_at            1             first_shared_at     A         5434512     NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_notebook_id_and_seq_in_nb  1             notebook_id         A         5434512     NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_notebook_id_and_seq_in_nb  2             seq_in_nb           A         5434512     NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_deleted_at                 1             deleted_at          A         452876      NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE   
notes 1           index_notes_on_comment_updated_at         1             comment_updated_at  A         1358628     NULL      NULL    YES   BTREE
```

`notes` table has ~6 million rows, in which ~3 million matchs `deleted_at IS NULL and shared = 1 and locked = 0`

`collection_notes` table has ~ 4 million rows.

SQL is:

```
SELECT `notes`.* FROM `notes` FORCE INDEX(`index_notes_on_comment_updated_at`) 
INNER JOIN `collection_notes` ON `notes`.`id` = `collection_notes`.`note_id` 
WHERE `notes`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND `collection_notes`.`collection_id` = ? 
AND `notes`.`shared` = 1 
AND `notes`.`locked` = 0
ORDER BY `notes`.`comment_updated_at` DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

When `collection_id = 47` which is relatively a very large collection, has more than 54000 notes, and it takes only 30ms, returns 15 rows, the first page.(Without FORCING this index `index_notes_on_comment_updated_at`, it takes around 1 second, this is why I am trying to optimize it)

When `collection_id = 270014` which is a very small collection, only has two notes, and it takes **101 seconds**! returns only 2 rows, which are the only two notes this collection has.(Without FORCING this index `index_notes_on_comment_updated_at`, it takes 30ms, which is very fast)

Why it behaves so differently and it's even slower when the data is small?

Following are the EXPLAINs:

The EXPLAIN **without FORCE INDEX** with `collection_id = 47`:

```
id  select_type table             type    possible_keys                                                                                                                 key                                                 key_len ref                                 rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      collection_notes  ref     index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id,index_collection_notes_on_collection_id,index_collection_notes_on_note_id index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id 5       const                               256478  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      notes             eq_ref  PRIMARY,index_notes_on_shared_and_locked,index_notes_on_deleted_at                                                            PRIMARY                                             4       maleskine.collection_notes.note_id  1       Using where
```

The EXPLAIN **without FORCE INDEX** with `collection_id = 270014`:

```
id  select_type table             type    possible_keys                                                                                                                 key                                                 key_len ref                                 rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      collection_notes  ref     index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id,index_collection_notes_on_collection_id,index_collection_notes_on_note_id index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id 5       const                               8     Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      notes             eq_ref  PRIMARY,index_notes_on_shared_and_locked,index_notes_on_deleted_at                                                            PRIMARY                                             4       maleskine.collection_notes.note_id  1     Using where
```

The EXPLAIN **with FORCE INDEX** with `collection_id = 270014`:

```
id  select_type table             type  possible_keys                                                                                                                 key                                                 key_len ref                       rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      notes             index NULL                                                                                                                          index_notes_on_comment_updated_at                   5       NULL                      15    Using where
1   SIMPLE      collection_notes  ref   index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id,index_collection_notes_on_collection_id,index_collection_notes_on_note_id index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id 10      const,maleskine.notes.id  1     Using index
```

The EXPLAIN **with FORCE INDEX** with `collection_id = 47`:

```
id  select_type table             type  possible_keys                                                                                                                 key                                                 key_len ref                       rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      notes             index NULL                                                                                                                          index_notes_on_comment_updated_at                   5       NULL                      15    Using where
1   SIMPLE      collection_notes  ref   index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id,index_collection_notes_on_collection_id,index_collection_notes_on_note_id index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id 10      const,maleskine.notes.id  1     Using index
```

My question is:

1. Why this `FORCE INDEX(`index_notes_on_comment_updated_at`)` accelerates query with `collection_id = 47`(has 50000+ notes) so much(1s -> 30ms) and meantime, makes query with `collection_id = 270014`(has only 2 notes) so slower(30ms -> 101s)
2. Without `FORCE INDEX(`index_notes_on_comment_updated_at`)`, how could I make the original query faster for big collection (like collection_id = 47) now it takes 1s to finish.

Original SQL:

```
SELECT `notes`.* FROM `notes` 
INNER JOIN `collection_notes` ON `notes`.`id` = `collection_notes`.`note_id` 
WHERE `notes`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND `collection_notes`.`collection_id` = ? 
AND `notes`.`shared` = 1 
AND `notes`.`locked` = 0
ORDER BY `notes`.`comment_updated_at` DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: could You add full table structure for both tables? at least indexes SHOW INDEX FROM notes, not very clean - what is it index_notes_on_comment_updated_at

Comment: @a_vlad Thanks. And I add full table structure and indexes for both tables.

Comment: to continue conversation - as example look at chooses indexes on Your 2 plans - without FORCE it choose PRIMARY for notes, showing rows = 1, it wrong, because we are not search by id, so You can look for all 4 plans and we can compare them

Comment: as You can see - mysql swap Your not proper query, and make it more fast by lookup first for 15 rows from notes, than for related records, for avoid full scan. Think in other 2 plans - situation would be different

Comment: looking at the plan with force index with collection_id = 270014, it also search for 15 rows, but it takes so much time, why is that?

Comment: look also for chosen indexes for this, rows - not give all information, You can see queries shaped - look tables name in row 1,2 and indexes

Comment: let me try explain in other words - for example You have 100 sorted by date day, and You need first 3 when sale was positive. If You have 40 day with positive sale Your probability for fetch this 3 in first 20% of rows - high, if You have only 3 this records - You will lookup over 80% of records. this is very simple explanation - what could be. MySQL stop when found FIRST 15 records with same node_id ... so - as much more sorted records, as much faster it found first 15

Comment: @larryzhao "looking at the plan with force index with collection_id = 270014, it also search for 15 rows, but it takes so much time, why is that?" Please note that the row number could be a approximately number its not a precise number if you are using the InnoDB engine so it could be MySQL needs to search more records in the index file

Comment: @larryzhao "looking at the plan with force index with collection_id = 270014, it also search for 15 rows, but it takes so much time, why is that?" Please note that the row number could be a approximately number its not a precise number if you are using the InnoDB engine so it could be MySQL needs to search more records in the index file

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` - it is more descriptive than `DESC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your case, index

> index_notes_on_comment_updated_at, include single column -
>   comment_updated_at

which is used nowhere in Your query in JOIN and/or WHERE part:

```
SELECT `notes`.* FROM `notes` FORCE INDEX(`index_notes_on_comment_updated_at`) 
INNER JOIN `collection_notes` ON `notes`.`id` = `collection_notes`.`note_id` 
WHERE `notes`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND `collection_notes`.`collection_id` = ? 
AND `notes`.`shared` = 1 
AND `notes`.`locked` = 0
ORDER BY `notes`.`comment_updated_at` DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

so, force MySQL to use this index - same as FORCE it to use FULL SCAN

> 'shared' and 'locked' - have very low cardinality,

so not reduce number of rows
in this case best choice let mysql use default key for JOIN and filter of rows will be by

```
`collection_notes`.`collection_id` =
```

which is included in 2 indexes in Your structure

plus change order in index - index_collection_notes_on_collection_id_and_note_id
for

> (note_id, collection_id) same as You use in query

**Edited after adding all plans**

*let look for collection_id = 47:*

original query:

> select 256478 records from collection_notes, than make lookup in notes
>   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
>   Using where

forced query:

> filter using FORCED INDEX 15 first records, than make lookup Using
>   where Using index

*for second case:*
with force index it choose index

> index_notes_on_comment_updated_at

and lookup for note_id

**Add example for Your question** - why with similar plan FORCED INDEX query work better for bigger collection:
[image]

Data sorted by date (yellow column) and with scan mysql must fetch first NNN records rom green columns

I not try explain - how indexes work, but in our case - mysql stop work after **first any equal records** **and number of this first records dramatically less than total number of correct records**

this is simple visual example, real data could have different frequency, but logic will be same - with big data-set and small number of equal data, query could (or could not) work faster then on smaller.

There are many other parameters could give affect, but this is one of possible scenarios what happens when index wrong.

Comment: But why forcing `index_notes_on_comment_updated_at` accelerates when `collection_id = 47`

Comment: first compare to explain plans without force - not fact both the same, mysql not always take same indexes depending from statistics, and by the way -test suggested index changes

Comment: I added the explain without forcing index. I understand that the index is not affective used in JOIN/WHERE. What I don't understand is,

1. Why it accelerates big collection so much, from 1s -> 30ms, but meanwhile slows down small collection so dramatically.

2. If I drop the FORCE INDEX, how to make it faster?

Comment: for this You need compare all 4 plans, with notes - plan for collection 47 with and without force, plan for collection #2 with and without, as example for big collection it could take by default more bad plan. Just add - we can not repeat exactly Your situation, because plan could be changed with different data, so need compare all variants - how many rows return in both case total? how many rows total in both table? create or not temp table and etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I added all the plans, total rows and rows returned to the question, but how could I check if temp table is created?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are ordered representation of the data, the table data is not, as MySQL has no general support for a clustered index, other than the `PRIMARY KEY` in InnoDB.

So when you force the updated_at index you are forcing the query to use that index, even if it is not optimal. This adds no value to the results, as it cannot be used to match your where conditions. Instead, afterwards the whole table has to be scanned (or some other index used) to actually perform your query.

For this query you want to use an index on note_id, collection_id (in this order). It might also help to have an index on note table: (id, shared, locked) or (id, shared), (id, locked)

Finally, have a look at my answer here for using binary values for your shared and locked fields: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4192/2599

Comment: But why forcing index_notes_on_comment_updated_at accelerates when collection_id = 47

Comment: Partially false -- InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, a clustered index on the data.  I often use this fact to create a PK to help performance.

Comment: @Rick which part is false?

Comment: Clustered index.  Granted there is no "general support" for such, only the "implicit"  clustering of the PK in InnoDB.  Would you care to rephrase you Answer?

Comment: Also, `collection_id` should be first, not `note_id`.  And it is almost never useful to have an index _starting_ with the `PRIMARY KEY` (`id`).

Comment: @Rick, please feel free to rewrite. I was meaning to explain the general concept of difference - it seems still correct to me

Answer (score 0):

(This Answer does not address the "why", but it brings up three other issues, with recommendations on how to improve performance.)

**Optimal Many:Many table design**

Follow the advice [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on how to build the optimal many:many table.  Having an `id` in a many:many table is a waste.  In particular, do this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(note_id, collection_id),
INDEX(collection_id, note_id)
```

This way, the query can be "Using index" -- that is a 'covering' index.

At this point, `PRIMARY KEY(id)` is optimal.  Alas, there is no practical way to optimize the `ORDER BY`; it will require a temp table and a file sort.

**Pagination**

It smells like you will be asking for the 'next' 15 notes?  If so, `OFFSET` is an inefficient way to do it.  Notice how you needed to look at all the notes for that collection?  Well, the next 15 will have to do that.  Further more it will have to skip over the first 15.  By the last 'page', you will have scanned every note many times.

[*How to paginate by remembering where you left off*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

**Lists**

A third tip will eliminate the filesort and probably let an index handle the `ORDER BY`.  But it involves some extra work.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists).